# MiniProfiler EF6 - Misleading "duplicate" queries

Tags: entity-framework-6, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm using MiniProfiler EF6 (3.0.10-beta4) on an MVC5 project with EF 6.1, and it's showing a number of "duplicate" entity framework queries in its output.

The parameters to the "duplicate" queries are identical and I've traced the call to one common location in my code where the query is executed, and I can see that the EF query is definitely being called multiple times.

However, when I use SQL Server Profiler to monitor the queries that are actually getting executed on the database, the query that MiniProfiler says is a duplicate only got sent to the database one time; all subsequent executions of that query were against the cached results in the DbContext.

Is this a new bug?  I found [an old StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585270/mvc-mini-profiler-falsely-showing-duplicate-queries) that sounds like the same issue, but it was reportedly fixed a long time ago.